# SQL: Inner Join On Next Record (In Relation to Key) Satisfying a Condition

Tags: sql

I am trying to do something along the lines of

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable t1
WHERE
INNER JOIN MyTable t2
ON (
?INF?(t2.Index > t1.Index AND t2.Attrib = t1.Attrib)
)
WHERE
t1.a = foo
t2.b = bar
```

By `?INF?` I mean the infinum i.e. the smallest `t2.index` satisfying the constraints in the bracket. `Index` is my primary key and is ordered natural numbers. `Attrib` can be any general attribute of the records in `MyTable`.

What is the actual SQL to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
ON t2.index = (
     SELECT min( index ) FROM MyTable t33
     WHERE t33.index > t1.Index 
       AND t33.Attrib = t1.Attrib
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works but is very slow for me. I am using SQLite and maybe it is running the whole `SELECT` and then finding the minimum. As `index` is indexed, I was wondering if there is a quicker way of doing it i.e. stopping once the lowest `index` satisfying the required conditions is found?

Comment: I don't know SQLite and cannot help. Most leading databases can optimize a query like this (with MIN function) using the index, for this condition a composite index on `Attrib+Index` columns usually gives the best performance (in this order: `Attrib+Index` - `Attrib` must be a leading column in the index).